# Is there a way to create custom product templates based on category on WooCommerce?

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic, production

so i am building a woocommerce site for software and i ran into an issue. There are free software that should redirected to an external site to download it, but there are also software that are premium and cost money. So basically i want to have 2 product templates: a normal one with price, cart, etc... and another one that has a button (lets say download) that redirects to an external website, without the cart, price and so on. Is it possible to do without doing the code myself, is there a plugin for that? Commercial plugins are also an option, but would like to find a solution that does not require that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are able to do this in Woocommerce, 
Custom build single-product template under woocommerce & apply conditional logic according to category ID(because in case in future you change name of category ID will remain same). This way you will be able to layout of the template.